# NGINX create subdomain that uses functions and assets from main Domain PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I'm currently developing a subdomain (mobile version) of my main page, this is the structure:

```
mywebsite.com
├──App
│   ├──Controllers
│   │  └──testController.php
│   └──Models
│      └──testModel.php
└──public
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css  
    ├── jquery
    │   └── jquery.js
    ├── js
    │   ├── bootstrap.js
    │   └── scripts.js
    ├── includes
    │   └──something.php
    ├── mobile
    │   └── index.php
    └── index.php
```

I'm trying to configure the subdomain and domain in my NGINX. The idea is that mobile/index.php will be **m**.mywebsite.com and working with files in css, js and includes that are in main domain.

Currently, accessing to mywebsite.com/mobile/index.php works and loads functions and files, like testModel.php or style.css, etc that are outside of mobile folder. But doesn't works when I try to access from subdomain URL due to it tries to search those files inside mobile, and there is no way to search outside subdomain.

What options do I have? Should I create an html file with iframe that will be the subdomain and load the mobile/index.php?

There is a way in the virtualhost file to change the url presentation when inside mobile folder and make it look like m.mybesite.com?

This is the virtualhost file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/test/mywebsite.com/public/mobile;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name m.mywebsite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
server {
        server_name mywebsite.com;
        root /var/www/test/mywebsite.com;
        index index.html index.php;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ .php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }  
}
server {
    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mywebsite.com;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid relational paths in your code. Use absolute paths in mobile/index.php and in index.php and problem will be fixed. Defining a constant like ROOT may be helpful. E.g. in index.php:

```
const ROOT = __DIR__ . '/..'; // one level higher than 'public' folder

include(ROOT . '/App/Models/testModel.php');
```

and in mobile/index.php:

```
const ROOT = __DIR__ . '/../..'; // two levels higher than 'public/mobile' folder

include(ROOT . '/App/Models/testModel.php');
```

P.S. Also, note that paths to files have nothing in common with domains or subdomains.

Comment: This is a really good approach to solve this problem, the only thing is in the HTML part I can't bring the assets for the mobile version like images because it always start at **http://m.mywebsite.com/**assets/images/example.png 

What should I do in these situations?

Comment: For  assets and pictures there is two options:
- you can create their own separated subdomain like `pictures.mywebsite.com`
- or you can reconfigure your webserver to serve assets and images from any subdomain. If your server does not provide such possibility (I am sure that nginx does), you could simply duplicate the configuration with another domain name, but the same root folder, so the same assets will be served from both domains.